# what is i = i[0] for? yolo, cv2

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, yolo

I am very new to computer vision with python. I found a script to run a yolo.weights file. Everything runs smoothly until it hits this part:

```
    for i in indices:
         i = i[0]
         box = bbox[i]
         x,y,w,h = box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]
         cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
         cv2.putText(img, f'{classNames[classIds[i]].capitalize()} {int(confs[i]*100)}%' (x+10,y+30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9,(255,255,255),2)
```

It gives the error:
File "script_location_etc", line 47, in findObjects
i = i[0]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

What exactly does i = i[0] even do? And what is another way to doing it.

Comment: where did you copy that code from? it's bad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you are trying to retrieve a value from an indexed location in a non iterable type.

`i = i[0]`  means get the first element of `i` and save it in the `i` variable.

So if i was iterable it would work like this:

```
>>> i = `some string`
>>> i = i[0]
>>> print(i)
... `s`
```

So basically your code is telling you that `i` isn't iterable and therefore there is no first element to get. I can't really tell why this might be happening without more details. Maybe try removing that line completely and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, the code does work. I though it meant something else other than getting the first value.

Comment: @ZackDaQuack - Another way of doing the same thing would be `for i, *_ in indices:` but whether thats better is debatable

Comment: @ZackDaQuack  cool glad you figured it out.